# UIViewController Not able to redirect

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Here is my problem. I had a UITableViewcontroller to which UINavigation controller is Embedded. To UITableviewController I had Add screen and an edit screen. Add screen is working perfectly. When I click on the records on the table view cell it is able to redirect to the edit page (detailed view). When I hit on Submit button the page is not navigating to the tableview cell. Here is the below error.

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Here is the code I was trying for navigation.

```
UINavigationController *questionnaireNavController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DLProjectsTasksubtasks"];
        [questionnaireNavController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        DLProjectsTasksubtasks *qvc = (DLProjectsTasksubtasks *)[questionnaireNavController topViewController];

        [qvc.tableView reloadData];
        [self presentViewController:questionnaireNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Between I was using a Segue for transfering the data from tableview data to Edit Screen

Comment: Why do you dismiss viewController immediately after presenting it?

Comment: No matter even if I remove the dismiss code it is not able to redirect

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve? you're presenting and dismissing at once without waiting for the `present` to finish. This will definitely give you an error.

Comment: Sami I had removed the dismissing code from that and even though it is not able to redirect

Comment: Look at your storyboard once more. Maybe there isn't any top view controller for questionnaireNavController.

Comment: have you tried calling dismiss on your submit action?

Comment: May I know how can we know whether it is a topview controller?

Comment: Yes I had Sami but It did not succeed

Comment: It is able to redirect from tableview cell to my detailed view controller but it is not able to redirect from Detailed view controller to tableview cell

Comment: is your segue push or is it modal?

Comment: if it is push, instead of dismiss, you should do a pop on your navigation controller.

Comment: It is a Push, May I know How can we do a pop on our navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your segue is being pushed on the navigation controller rather than being presented modally. So you have two options, either change the segue in your storyboard to be modal and use the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:` or keep it the way it is and use `popViewControllerAnimated:` on your navigation controller.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

For passing the data to the previous page you can either pass a reference of the previous view controller OR accessing it through your `navigationController.viewControllers`. Index n-2 will be your previous view controller (n is the count of viewControllers).

Comment: I was trying to pass the data also to that page Sami

Comment: to the previous page?

Comment: Yes, According to the projectid I was trying to display in tableview

Comment: If I change the segue to a modal it is giving me some error and crashes the application

Comment: When I change the segue to Modal Here is the below error Application tried to present modally an active controller <DLProjectsTasksubtasks: 0xeb2a980>

Comment: For passing the data to the previous page you can either pass a reference of the previous view controller OR accessing it through your navigationController.viewControllers. Index n-2 will be your previous view controller (n is the count of viewControllers).